# Design rules for power AB amplifier stage

Tags: power, transistors, amplifier, design, bjt

could you please point me to a good guide for a simple class AB power amplifier design based on BJTs (referring to the "classic" schema with complementary push pull, diodes to remove cross over, resistances to bias the diodes, dual voltage) ? I already have good enough knowledge for class A, BJT biasing, emitter follower, etc. But I need to get clarified on the details of power stage like:

1. correct chose of component values (resistances, diodes, power BJTs)
2. how to get the maximum voltage swing
3. how to reduce as much as possible the quiescent current of the power BJTs
4. some advice on build on breadboard of the power stage
5. any other is welcome

thank you!

Alvise

Comment: There are votes to close your question. Maybe you will be provided better help if you split your question and ask them individually, i.e. (i) How do I get as much voltage swing as possible? (ii) How do I find out what's the lowest practical quiescent current (or the best tradeoff for it), ...

Answer (score 1):

In a general sense a "good guide" would be this book: "Audio Power Amplifier Design Handbook" by Douglas Self, currently at fifth edition. If you don't have that book yet, I'd suggest getting it, as you'll learn a lot about power amplifiers.

Incidentally, Douglas Self has this to say about Class AB amps: "Class-AB is less linear than either A or B, and in my view its only legitimate use is as a fallback mode to allow Class-A amplifiers to continue working reasonably when faced with a low-load impedance."